# How to revert changes from a AWS Glue crawler run?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I recently ran a AWS glue crawler with the intention to create 1 table but accidentally created almost 15k tables from that table. The tables are in Athena and right now the only way to delete it is it do this manually.  I would delete the whole database and start over but there are tables in there which I already need. Is there a way I can just revert the changes from that one specific run?

[image]

Comment: You don't have to do it manually, you can write a script to do it using the API.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, other than restoring the database from a backup, there is no other way to revert changes here besides manual deletion.